# "infinitesimal" of a measure in order to substitute inside an integral

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In the context of the Lévy-Khintchine formula, I have certain integral

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{lk}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \Big( e^{it'x} - 1 - i \frac{t'x}{1 - x'x} \Big)d\nu(x), \quad t \in \mathbb{R}^p  
\end{equation}

where $\nu$ is a measure defined on $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Suppose that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} |x|^2 d \nu(x)<\infty$$

Define:
$$\kappa(E) = \int_{E} |x|^2 d \nu(x), \quad E \subset \mathbb{R}^p.$$

I want to get $d\kappa(x)$ as a function of $d\nu(x)$ in order to do a substitution in (\ref{lk}), but I don't know how to differentiate $\kappa$:
$$d\kappa(x) = ? d\nu(x)$$

Some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Radon-Nikodym derivative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem).

If $\kappa(E) = \int_{E} |x|^2 d \nu(x)$ for all measurable $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$, then $|x|^2$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\kappa$ with respect to $\nu$.  Some notations are
$$
|x|^2 = \frac{d\kappa}{d\nu}(x)\quad\text{or}\quad
|x|^2\;d\nu(x) = {d\kappa}(x) .
$$
The meaning of each of these is:
$$
\int \varphi(x)\;d\kappa(x) = \int \varphi(x)\;|x|^2\;d\nu(x)
$$
for all appropriate functions $\varphi$.